# Azure Notification Hub - Limit on registrations

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

What is the limit on registrations to cause a `403` for register create/update?

According to the documentation, registration create/update (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223265.aspx) may return a 403.

So there must be some kind of limit, though I'm not sure what the limit is.  The pricing page does not say anything about a registration limit.

the error per the api spec is below

```
403 Quota exceeded; too many registrations in this namespace. Registration not created
```

what causes the 403?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please show the code that you are using where this error is happening.

Comment: the error is not occurring, but rather it is specified in the api docs. so i need to know how/what causes a 403.

Comment: i had to re edit the question since it was incorrectly edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number of registrations is not limited. There is a throttling for CRUD operation's rate. Quotas depend on tire your are but it is not going to be less then 2000 operations per minute per namespace any way. If quota is exceed then service returns 403.

Comment: thanks. i dont know how u know these details but excellent answer.

Comment: @efimovandr: Could you have a look at [my similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484046/getting-quotaexceededexception-what-are-the-operation-quota-limitations-for-az)? Seems like you work on Azure Notification Hubs at Microsoft, is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is true. I've written comment to you  question. I usually keep track on  questions about NH, but sometimes code writing takes all my time :)