# Getting QuotaExceededException - What are the operation quota limitations for Azure Notification Hubs?

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I was doing some latency/performance testing for sending push notifications with Azure Notification Hub by consecutively sending many notifications in a foreach loop. It worked fine for 100 "SendNotification" requests, altough it was relatively slow (14s), but I got a `QuotaExceededException` for 1000 requests in a row:

> [QuotaExceededException: The remote server returned an error: (403)
>   Forbidden. The request was terminated because the namespace
>   pushnotification-testing is being throttled. Please wait 60 seconds
>   and try again. TrackingId:...

Even when I don't wait for 60 seconds as advised, I can again execute 100 consecutive requests, but 1000 requests in a row always fail... Anything slightly above 100 consecutive requests fails most of the time...

I couldn't find any documentation on these limitations. This should be documented somewhere, so I can be sure Azure Notification Hubs will fit my needs.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474902/azure-notification-hub-limit-on-registrations) says

> There is a throttling for CRUD operation's rate. Quotas depend on tire
>   your are but it is not going to be less then 2000 operations per
>   minute per namespace any way. If quota is exceed then service returns
>   403.

For me, it seems to be less then 2000 operations. By the way, I'm using "FREE" tier for testing, but I guess we would switch to "STANDARD" for production.

Has anyone similar experiences or knows where to look for more information?

**In particular, what are the operation quota limitations per timefram for the different tiers of Azure Notification Hubs?**

UPDATE1: It's weird, but I sending **1000 requests in parallel works most of the time**, but **consecutively it fails on the 101st request**.

Comment: Do you set enableTestSend=true creating NotificationHubClient instance? If so then you are throttled by the special policy for test sends, it happens because test send feature was introduced only for debug/troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: @efimovandr: No, I didn't use that parameter...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For my best knowledge for right now NH has following limitations on number of **SENDS (not registrations) per namespace per minute per NH machine**:

Free tire: 100
Basic tire: 900
Standard tire: 11500

Massive sending in parallel allows to send more because calls are very likely to be routed on different machines.

Comment: I guess there is no official documentation for this at the moment?

Comment: No such docs as far as I know. NH is really good in terms of performance and we are continuously working on improvements based on customers' needs. So if you have any concerns about performance it is always subject to discuss, just contact us.

Comment: With these limits I wonder how one can "Scale instantly to millions of devices" as marketed by Azure Notification Hub page.

Comment: To add my experience, I got the throttle exception when I was querying the `GetInstallation` endpoint multiple times. So who knows what else is throttled, and it's and issue that may only be revealed when in production with actual large amounts of data.